# Configure Webpack with es6 react and jsx

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, reactjs

I tried following [this blog post](https://www.codementor.io/tamizhvendan/beginner-guide-setup-reactjs-environment-npm-babel-6-webpack-du107r9zr) to setup a project using **react jsx** and **es6** but webpack build fail on parsing the jsx

> ERROR in ./src/index.jsx Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected
>   token (5:7)

when i try to not use jsx the project build is successful but the generated file still contains es6 elements like **import** so it seems like babel is not doing anything at all.

My project contains the following files:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "playground",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.jsx",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "lodash": "^4.15.0",
    "react": "^15.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'target');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');

var config = {
    entry: APP_DIR + '/index.jsx',
    output: {
        path: BUILD_DIR,
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module : {
        loaders : [
            {
                test : /\.jsx?/,
                include : APP_DIR,
                loader : 'babel'
            }
        ]
    },
};

module.exports = config;
```

.babelrc

```
{
    "presets" : ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Playground</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"/>
        <script src="target/bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

src/index.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

render(<div>Hello</div>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: If you want to have it real simple, you could use create-react-app instead: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app .

Comment: To continue what @FelixKling said - setting up all the tools for a fresh react project is not simple, which is why there are many available boilerplates / starter kits / generators. You should use one of them and learn by example (create-react-app is a good one)